# Can I use require("path").join to safely concatenate urls?

Tags: node.js, url, string-concatenation

Is this safe to use `require("path").join` to concatenate URLs, for example:

```
require("path").join("http://example.com", "ok"); 
//returns 'http://example.com/ok'

require("path").join("http://example.com/", "ok"); 
//returns 'http://example.com/ok'
```

If not, what way would you suggest for doing this without writing code full of ifs?

Comment: See also https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2216

Comment: In case anyone wants to use path.join, but avoid issues on Windows: `path.posix.join('/one/two/three', 'four') // '/one/two/three/four`, `path.posix.join('/one/two/three/', 'four') // '/one/two/three/four`, `path.posix.join('/one/two/three/', '/four') // '/one/two/three/four`

Comment: @TimothyZorn The problem is that it if you do something like this `path.posix.join('http://localhost:9887/one/two/three/', '/four')`, the join gets rid of one of the double slashes in `http://`

Comment: Ahh, yeah - good point. In those scenarios, you'd want to do something like `'http://localhost:9887/one/two/three/'.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/, '') + '/' + '/four'.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/, '')` and you *could* do `String.prototype.trimSlashes = function() { return this.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/, ''); }` if you don't want to type the regular expression over and over again. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22387870/2537258

Comment: or `['http://localhost:9887/one/two/three/', '/four'].map((part) => part. replace(/^\/+|\/+$/, '')).join('/')`

Answer (score 243, accepted):

No. `path.join()` will return incorrect values when used with URLs.

It sounds like you want `new URL()`.  From the [WHATWG URL Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-class):

```js
new URL('/one', 'http://example.com/').href    // 'http://example.com/one'
new URL('/two', 'http://example.com/one').href // 'http://example.com/two'
```

Note that `url.resolve` is now marked as deprecated in the [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_resolve_from_to).

As Andreas correctly points out in a comment, `url.resolve` (also [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost)) would only help if the problem is as simple as the example.  `url.parse` also applies to this question because it returns consistently and predictably formatted fields via the `URL` object that reduces the need for "code full of ifs". However, `new URL()` is also the replacement for `url.parse`.

Comment: Although not exactly what I was looking for this also solves my problem. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @AndreasHultgren the first comment is correct. If the example was `url.resolve('/one/two/three/', 'four')` then the output would be `'one/two/three/four'`.

Comment: @tavnab three years later I see that the comments indeed has the expected output, but my point was mainly that url.resolve might not quite be what the op asked for. It can even be dangerous if user input is not properly sanitized (e.g.`url.resolve('/one/two/three/', '../four')`), a problem a naive `.join()` doesn't have.

Comment: @AndreasHultgren Totally agreed. I just wanted to make it clear that `url.resolve()` indeed doesn't have the same semantics as `.join()`, as when I first read your comment I misinterpreted it as, "`url.resolve('/one/two/three', 'four')` should be expected to output `'/one/two/three/four'`".

Comment: In case anyone wants to use path.join, but avoid issues on Windows: `path.posix.join('/one/two/three', 'four') // '/one/two/three/four`, `path.posix.join('/one/two/three/', 'four') // '/one/two/three/four`, `path.posix.join('/one/two/three/', '/four') // '/one/two/three/four`

Comment: The comments are incorrect, `url.resolve('/one/two/three', 'four')         // '/one/two/four'` in the answer is correct

Comment: Also be aware `url.resolve()` only takes 2 arguments, where as `path.join()` takes any number. So depending on what you're doing you may need to nest calls, eg.. `url.resolve(url.resolve(SERVER_URL, pagePath), queryString)`

Comment: Basically, `url.resolve` is resolving a relative URL (2nd param) based on an absolute URL (first param). Very useful but also very different from what `path.join` gives us.

Comment: This answer should be updated to reflect the new WHATWG URL api (the legacy url API is deprecated): `const url = new URL('/one/two/three', 'https://example.com')`

Comment: In what use case does `path.join()` return incorrect values when joining url parts? The examples of the op look fine. Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 61):

No, you should not use `path.join()` to join URL elements.

There's a package for doing that now. So rather than reinvent the wheel, write all your own tests, find bugs, fix them, write more tests, find an edge case where it doesn't work, etc., you could use this package.

### url-join

https://github.com/jfromaniello/url-join

### Install

`npm install url-join`

### Usage

```
var urljoin = require('url-join');

var fullUrl = urljoin('http://www.google.com', 'a', '/b/cd', '?foo=123');

console.log(fullUrl);
```

Prints:

'http://www.google.com/a/b/cd?foo=123'

Comment: This. This is fantastic. Thank you.

Comment: note that you can't use it in NodeJS as the package is written in es6 modules or you need to configure your environment to work with es6 modules

Answer (score 42):

This can be accomplished by a combination of Node's [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) and [URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html):

1. Require the packages:

```
const nodeUrl = require('url')
const nodePath = require('path')
```

2. Start by making a URL object to work with:

```
> const myUrl = new nodeUrl.URL('https://example.com')
```

3. Use `pathname=` and `path.join` to construct any possible combination:

```
> myUrl.pathname = nodePath.join('/search', 'for', '/something/')
'/search/for/something/'
```

*(you can see how liberal `path.join` is with arguments)*

4. At this point your URL reflects the ultimate desired result:

```
> myUrl.toString()
'https://example.com/search/for/something/'
```

### Why this approach?

This technique uses built-in libraries. The less third-party dependencies the better, when it comes to CVEs, maintenance, etc.

Nothing will be more proven or better tested than standard libs.

## PS: Never manipulate URLs as strings!

When I review code I'm adamant about **never manipulating URLs as strings manually**. For one, look how complicated [the spec is](https://url.spec.whatwg.org).

Secondly, the absence/presence of a trailing/prefixed slash (`/`) should not cause everything to break! You should never do:

```
const url = `${baseUrl}/${somePath}`
```

and especially not:

```
uri: host + '/' + SAT_SERVICE + '/' + CONSTELLATION + '/',
```

Of which I have seen.

Comment: this should be higher up - reliable url construction with only built in packages

Comment: It's better to return myUrl.href instead of calling toString()

Comment: with the addition of `.href` from @Hoppe by far the best approach!

Comment: I think it is worth noting that `path.join` in windows  returns a string separated with "\" instead of "/". but when we set this string as `url.pathname`, it converts all the "\"s into "/" itself. So the final result is correct although the `path.join` output was not.

Answer (score 23):

**Axios** has a helper function that can combine URLs.

```
function combineURLs(baseURL, relativeURL) {
  return relativeURL
    ? baseURL.replace(/\/+$/, '') + '/' + relativeURL.replace(/^\/+/, '')
    : baseURL;
}
```

> Source:
>   https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/fe7d09bb08fa1c0e414956b7fc760c80459b0a43/lib/helpers/combineURLs.js

Comment: Very cute solution, copy+paste :)

Comment: For me because I already uses axios, I do `const combineURLs = require('axios/lib/helpers/combineURLs');`

Answer (score 9):

The [WHATWG URL object](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_the_whatwg_url_api) constructor has a `(input, base)` version, and the `input` can be relative using `/`, `./`, `../`.  Combine this with `path.posix.join` and you can do anything:

```js
const {posix} = require ("path");
const withSlash = new URL("https://example.com:8443/something/");
new URL(posix.join("a", "b", "c"), withSlash).toString(); // 'https://example.com:8443/something/a/b/c'
new URL(posix.join("./a", "b", "c"), withSlash).toString(); // 'https://example.com:8443/something/a/b/c'
new URL(posix.join("/a", "b", "c"), withSlash).toString(); // 'https://example.com:8443/a/b/c'
new URL(posix.join("../a", "b", "c"), withSlash).toString(); // 'https://example.com:8443/a/b/c'
const noSlash = new URL("https://example.com:8443/something");
new URL(posix.join("./a", "b", "c"), noSlash).toString(); // 'https://example.com:8443/a/b/c'
```

Answer (score 7):

No! On Windows `path.join` will join with backslashes. HTTP urls are always forward slashes.

How about

```
> ["posts", "2013"].join("/")
'posts/2013'
```

Comment: Good idea, but what if the first argument already have a slash at the end? eg.: `["posts/", "2013"].join("/")`?

Comment: @RenatoGama, `posts//2013` is still a valid URL.

Comment: ^ that will not work on all domains, even though it is a valid URI.

Comment: Specifically, Node's Express does not ignore extraneous slashes for routing.

Comment: In case anyone wants to use path.join, but avoid issues on Windows: `path.posix.join('/one/two/three', 'four') // '/one/two/three/four`, `path.posix.join('/one/two/three/', 'four') // '/one/two/three/four`, `path.posix.join('/one/two/three/', '/four') // '/one/two/three/four`

Comment: @Goodwine It's valid, but pointing to a **different** location. You can also have valid URLs with 3, 4 or 5 slashes in them, but all will point to different locations. So yes it is a problem and you need to make sure you are not doubling slashes when joining.

Answer (score 7):

If you use Angular, you can use [Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location):

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
// ...
Location.joinWithSlash('beginning', 'end');
```

Works only on 2 arguments though, so you have to chain calls or write a helper function to do that if needed.

Answer (score 6):

When I tried PATH for concatenating url parts I run into problems.
`PATH.join` stripes '//' down to '/' and this way invalidates an absolute url (eg. http://... -> http:/...).
For me a quick fix was:

```
baseurl.replace(/\/$/,"") + '/' + path.replace(/^\//,"") )
```

or with the solution posted by Colonel Panic:

```
[pathA.replace(/^\/|\/$/g,""),pathB.replace(/^\/|\/$/g,"")].join("/")
```

Comment: What if i'm trying to build a root-relative URL like this: `/assets/foo`? It will result into current-path-relative URL `assets/foo`.

Answer (score 4):

We do it like this:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

function urlJoin(a, b) {
  return _.trimEnd(a, '/') + '/' + _.trimStart(b, '/');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using **lodash**, you can use this simple oneliner:

```
// returns part1/part2/part3
['part1/', '/part2', '/part3/'].map((s) => _.trim(s, '/')).join('/')
```

inspired by **@Peter Dotchev's** answer

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use:

```
function joinUrlElements() {
  var re1 = new RegExp('^\\/|\\/$','g'),
      elts = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return elts.map(function(element){return element.replace(re1,""); }).join('/');
}
```

example:

```
url = joinUrlElements(config.mgmtServer, '/v1/o/', config.org, '/apps');
```

Comment: What if i'm trying to build a root-relative URL like this: `/assets/foo`? It will result into current-path-relative URL `assets/foo`.

Comment: prepend a slash ?   I mean, it's a simple check; you can add it yourself.

Comment: This is how it begins... next thing you know you've spent a cumulative 8+ hours finding edge cases that don't work and fixing them over the course of your project.

Answer (score 1):

There are other working answers, but I went with the following. A little path.join/URL combo.

```
const path = require('path');
//
const baseUrl = 'http://ejemplo.mx';
// making odd shaped path pieces to see how they're handled.
const pieces = ['way//', '//over/', 'there/'];
//
console.log(new URL(path.join(...pieces), baseUrl).href);
// http://ejemplo.mx/way/over/there/

// path.join expects strings. Just an example how to ensure your pieces are Strings.
const allString = ['down', 'yonder', 20000].map(String);
console.log(new URL(path.join(...allString), baseUrl).href);
// http://ejemplo.mx/down/yonder/20000
```

Comment: query params won't join as expected

Comment: Example? This works for us.

Answer (score 1):

By the time posting this answer `url.resolve()` is deprecated;

I did following to join to path in Nodejs:

```
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');


let myUrl = new URL('http://ignore.com');
myUrl.pathname=path.join(firstpath, secondpath);
console.log(myUrl.pathname)
```

This approach logs correct url path and it works for my case.

What is your opinion about this approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typescript custom solution:

```js
export function pathJoin(parts: string[], sep: string) {
  return parts
    .map(part => {
      const part2 = part.endsWith(sep) ? part.substring(0, part.length - 1) : part;
      return part2.startsWith(sep) ? part2.substr(1) : part2;
    })
    .join(sep);
}

expect(pathJoin(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], '/')).toEqual('a/b/c/d');
expect(pathJoin(['a/', '/b/', 'c/', 'd'], '/')).toEqual('a/b/c/d');
expect(pathJoin(['http://abc.de', 'users/login'], '/')).toEqual('http://abc.de/users/login');
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
path.join(SERVER_URL, imageAbsolutePath).replace(':/','://');
```

Edit: if you want to support windows enviroments

```
path.join(SERVER_URL, imageAbsolutePath).replace(/\\/g,'/').replace(':/','://');
```

The second solution will replace all the backslashes, so url parts like querystring and hash may be altered too, but the topic is joining just the url path, so I don't consider it an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of the built-in path and URL libraries provides the best solution.

The answers above, however, do not handle the case where you have a relative url (ie: "../foo") that you want to add to an existing URL (ie: "http://example.com/test/bar").  Simply doing `new URL("../foo","http://example.com/test/bar").href` would yield "http://example.com/foo", erroneously (for me) discarding the remainder of the original path.

A simple solution is:

```
var base = "http://example.com:8080/foo/bar";
var rel = "../test";
var resolved = new URL( path.resolve(new URL(base).pathname, rel ), base ).href;
// Result: http://example.com:8080/foo/test
```

Note: If you care about URL Search Params (which seems unlikely in this scenario), you would save each of the pieces above to discrete variables and set the new `url.searchParams = oldUrl.searchParams` before getting the href output.