# Add methods to Array.prototype, without the side effects

Tags: javascript, prototype, for-in-loop

I'd like to add an "insert" method on Arrays.
So I'm doing it like this:

```
> Array.prototype.insert = function(index, element){
    this.splice(index, 0, element);
};
```

And it works:

```
> a = [1,2,3]
[1, 2, 3]
> a.insert(0, 4)
undefined
> a
[4, 1, 2, 3]
```

But there's an undesired side effect:

```
> for (i in a){console.log(i)}
0
1
2
3
insert

> for (i in a){console.log(a[i])}
4
1
2
3
function (index, element){
    this.splice(index, 0, element);
}
```

This behavior is not intended and breaks other libraries that I use.
Is there any elegant solution for this?

Comment: That's why you should never use `for..in` on an array.

Comment: You can still use the other construction of the `for` loop: `for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) { console.log(a[i]); }`

Comment: Agreed! But nowadays we tend to reuse a lot of other people's code, and its hard to ensure that rule on all libs.

Comment: In fact, that's a great argument against doing what you're trying to do. Don't modify objects you don't own. http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859828/javascript-what-dangers-are-in-extending-array-prototype

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) works, but it won't be supported in older browsers. ([compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Object.defineProperty))

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'insert', {
  enumerable: false,
  value: function(index, element){
    this.splice(index, 0, element);
  }
});
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/GV5Z4/)

Comment: It works, thanks!! Do you happen to have a compatibility table for it anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

In this loop inherited properties (insert method) are not displayed.

```
  for (i in a){if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {console.log(i)}}
```

So, every object descended from Object inherits the hasOwnProperty method. This method can be used to determine whether an object has the specified property as a direct property of that object; unlike the in operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype chain.

This method compatible with all browsers

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm not willing to change the loop styles in the js libraries imported on my page.