# How to write own array method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, callback

```js
Array.prototype.ownMethod = function(x) {
  x(this)
}

[1, 2, 3, 4].ownMethod(function(x) {
  return x[1]
}) // This callback won't work .
```

I tried to pass array value inside my First-class function.  This method won't work for me.

Comment: You want a method to which you can pass a callback to be executed with your array ? It's not very clear

Comment: My method can take array, inside callback function's aurgument

Comment: Why not simply calling `console.log(array[1])` directly on the array instead of creating a function that takes a callback to which you pass `console.log(param[1])` it seams like code repetition to me.

Comment: @Nicolas Your full  code help me to understand

Comment: Side note: Never add to `Array.prototype` via assignment like that. [Do this instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22387870/157247).

Answer (score 6):

You've been caught out by Automatic Semicolon Insertion.

The function expression creates an object (the function) and the square bracket immediately after it is used as a property accessor instead of an array literal.

Add an explicit end of statement with a semi-colon to fix that.

```js
Array.prototype.ownMethod = function(x) {
  x(this)
};

[1, 2, 3, 4].ownMethod(function(x) {
  console.log(x[1]);
})
```