# Is there a replacement for url.resolve for creating URLs in Node?

Tags: node.js, url, path, resolve

I read on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301503/can-i-use-requirepath-join-to-safely-concatenate-urls) that you can concatenate URLs using url.resolve:

```
url.resolve('http://example.com/', 'image.jpg')    // 'http://example.com/image.jpg'
```

But upon reading the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_resolve_from_to) I see that this is now deprecated.  Is there a replacement for url.resolve?

Comment: "*Deprecated: Use the WHATWG URL API instead.*" - from the link you posted.

Comment: Sorry, this will sound stupid, but I couldn't find the function on the [WHATWG URL API](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) documentation ...

Comment: `new URL(input[, base])` -> `new URL('/foo', 'https://example.org/'); // https://example.org/foo` - isn't that what you need?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed.  I guess I got confused because new URL returns an object, not the string I was looking for.  I then just had to grab the href using object.href.  Thanks for your feedback here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, so with a bit of help from the comments, I managed to work out the solution:

```
const url_object = new URL('image.jpg', 'http://example.com/')
const url_string = url_object.href  // http://example.com/image.jpg
```

Being a little new to this, I didn't realise I had to pull the href out of the object returned from new URL.